# Numbering is reversed when iterating json data with jQuery's each

Tags: jquery, json, html

I have a jQuery `each` function that returns a list of records. The data is quiz questions and answers, and I need to number the question. But to my surprise, the numbering starts from the end. Below is my code:

```
var html;
var pno = 0;
$.each(data.results, function (i, r) {
    pno += 1;

    html = '<div class="questions"><h3 class="quest">' + pno + '&nbsp;' +
        r.QuestionText + '</h3><ul>';

    $.each(r.Answers, function (i, ans) {
        html += '<li>' + ans.AnswerLabel + '&nbsp;<input type="radio" data-question="' + ans.QuestionId + '" name="answer" value="' + ans.AnswerId + '"/>' + ans.AnswerText + '</li>';
    });

    html += '</ul><input type="submit" style="float:left"  value="Previous" class="orange-button prev">' +
    '<input type="submit" value="Next >>" class="orange-button next"></div>'
    $(".dummy").after(html);
});
```

The `pno` variable was meant to be the question number.

Comment: You keep adding the new element right after the `.dummy` element, yet the `.dummy` element stays where it is (`.after` does this). That means you keep adding *new* elements *before* the old ones (not after them).

Comment: $(".dummy").before(html); :) you adding element in reverse order

Comment: As addition to my comment, [here's a simple GIF to demonstrate](http://i.imgur.com/788bfvb.gif).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cache the question and answer DIVs in a variable outside of the outer `$.each` loop and insert the html at once after the the `$.each` loop. Also it's a best practice to modify the DOM elements at once rather than inside a loop.

```
var html;
var pno = 0;
var qWithA='';
$.each(data.results, function (i, r) {
    pno += 1;

    html = '<div class="questions"><h3 class="quest">' + pno + '&nbsp;' +
        r.QuestionText + '</h3><ul>';

    $.each(r.Answers, function (i, ans) {
        html += '<li>' + ans.AnswerLabel + '&nbsp;<input type="radio" data-question="' + ans.QuestionId + '" name="answer" value="' + ans.AnswerId + '"/>' + ans.AnswerText + '</li>';
    });

    html += '</ul><input type="submit" style="float:left"  value="Previous" class="orange-button prev">' +
    '<input type="submit" value="Next >>" class="orange-button next"></div>'
    qWithA += html;
});
$(".dummy").after(qWithA);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably confused [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) with [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/). Using the latter will work as expected:

```js
var data = { 
    results: [
        {
            QuestionText: 'Coffee?', 
            Answers: [
                {AnswerLabel: 'Yes', AnswerId: 1},
                {AnswerLabel: 'No', AnswerId: 2}
            ]
        },{
            QuestionText: 'Tea?', 
            Answers: [
                {AnswerLabel: 'Yes', AnswerId: 3},
                {AnswerLabel: 'No', AnswerId: 4}
            ]
        }
    ]
};
    
var html;
var pno = 0;
$.each(data.results, function (i, r) {
    pno += 1;

    html = '<div class="questions"><h3 class="quest">' + pno + '&nbsp;' +
        r.QuestionText + '</h3><ul>';

    $.each(r.Answers, function (i, ans) {
        html += '<li>' + ans.AnswerLabel + '&nbsp;<input type="radio" data-question="' + ans.QuestionId + '" name="answer" value="' + ans.AnswerId + '"/>' + ans.AnswerText + '</li>';
    });

    html += '</ul><input type="submit" style="float:left"  value="Previous" class="orange-button prev">' +
    '<input type="submit" value="Next >>" class="orange-button next"></div>'
    $(".dummy").append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dummy"></div>
```